# How to access json file in bitbucket pipeline?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a bitbucket pipeline that runs Google Lighthouse. I want to access the json output that is generated at the end of the pipeline and have it echo 1 of the variables. I understand that I can use artifacts, but I am unsure of how to access it.

Here is my bitbucket-pipelines.yml file:

```
script:
          - lhci collect
          - lhci upload
          - echo "===== Lighthouse has completed running ====="
        artifacts: # defining the artifacts to be passed to each future step.
          - .lighthouseci/*.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Reciting the [official doc](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-artifacts-in-steps/),

> Artifacts are files that are produced by a step. Once you've defined them in your pipeline configuration, you can share them with a following step or export them to keep the artifacts after a step completes. For example, you might want to use reports or JAR files generated by a build step in a later deployment step. Or you might like to download an artifact generated by a step, or upload it to external storage.

If you have your json file generated right after `echo "===== Lighthouse has completed running ====="` line, you don't have to define a separate step for echoing its contents. Do it right here. You don't even need artifacts if that's the only thing you want to do with your json.